# Turkish characters in UITableViewController and SQLite statements

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite, utf-8, uitableview

I am writing one application for iPhone. It reads data from "sqlite" database, puts data in `NSMutableArray` and displays the data in `UITableView` ("indexPath" correspond to the `id` column in the database). One column in the database is `turkish_words` and it contains Turkish words with Turkish characters like `İöşüçğı`. I'm reading data from the database using "FMDB framework".

```
NSArray  *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *docsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *dbPath = [docsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:dbFileName];

FMDatabase *database = [FMDatabase databaseWithPath:dbPath];
[database open];
NSString *sqlSelectQuery = @"SELECT id,turkish_word FROM words";
```

Then I'm adding data to the `NSMutableArray` like this:

```
FMResultSet *resultsWithNameLocation = [database executeQuery:sqlSelectQuery];
while([results next]) {
    NSString *strID = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[results intForColumn:dbIDKey]];
    NSString *strTur = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[results stringForColumn:dbTurkishKey]];

[self.words insertObject:[strTur lowercaseString] atIndex:[strID integerValue]];

}
```

All this code is in the `AppDelegate.m`

`UITableView` is then populated with data from `appDelegate.words` in other `UITableViewController`.

The problem is next. Cells with Turkish characters are looking like [This](http://www.dropbox.com/s/prlsebx3fg6ssow/Screenshot%202014-05-11%2014.38.21.png):
[image]

Now lets say that I want details for the word. New `UIView` is going to be pushed when I click to the cell containing word. Word is passed to "DetailViewController" in

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
```

Everything is working and I'm getting the word I clicked in "DetailViewController". Now I'm trying to create `SELECT` statement based on the word I got from previous `UITableViewController`. When I `NSLog` it, it's look good, for example:

**SELECT id,turkish_word,detail FROM words WHERE turkish_word="fi̇ldi̇şi̇ sahi̇li̇"**

It looks good, but get 0 rows for the result. When I run the query using "sqlite bash", it also returns 0 rows, but when I type it, I get row which I want. Bear in mind that copied one and typed one are looking the same, copied one is copied from `NSLog` and it returns 0 rows, and the typed one returns result I want.

I really don't know what to do about this.

Comment: What is the `PRAGMA encoding` of your database? Are you confident that the original string and the string you're inserting are both using the same string encoding? You can use `dataForColumn` and `NSLog` the resulting `NSData` to confirm the actual representation in your database (e.g. `6669cc87 6c6469cc 87c59f69 cc872073 616869cc 876c69cc 87`). Repeat this process for the string you're using in your `WHERE` clause and compare the hex representations. I'd also advise using `?` placeholders in your SQL rather than building SQL with `stringWithFormat`.

Comment: Or, could the behavior you're experiencing result from the fact that you're doing `lowercaseString` on the values you're retrieving from the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was encountering because I was adding `[myNSString lowercaseString]` to my `NSMutableArray` with words. It seems that string encoding was altered in that process, resulting that I was not able to query selected cell text.

Instead I've added original records to the `NSMutableArray`, and created separate NSStrings in method:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

and then used `[myString lowercaseString]`